# SSRS - Line chart exceeds maximum Y value

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS line chart whose maximum Y axis value is set to 101. The line displays points whose maximum value is 100 but there is an effect on the line where it seems the line exceeds the maximum value of 100.

I upload an image of my chart where we can see that around the X values 8 and 10, it seems the line exceeds 100 on the Y value but the maximum Y value is 100 in my data (The data is shown in the right table, Tamis is the X value and % Passant is the Y value).

The link to the image is below:

https://ibb.co/w051ddQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using **Smooth Line** chart. The Smooth part of the chart rounds off the line and can show the line go above the maximum and minimum values.

If you switch to a regular Line Chart, the line would go straight from one point to another without trying to round it off.

Comment: Thank you and indeed a regular line chart solves the problem.